# URL parameters configured with TYPO3 routeEnhancers missing in form action URLs

Tags: routes, typo3

I'm trying to use the routeEnhancers in TYPO3. The URL I want to support is

[www.xyz.com/some/path/BIN#VALUE#](http://www.xyz.com/some/path/BIN#VALUE#)

`#VALUE#` is a dynamic value. The configuration to access the page works as expected. But on the page is a form control and there the URL misses the `#VALUE#`

`<form action="/some/path/BIN"`

My configuration is:

```
  Bins:
    type: Simple
    limitToPages: [213]
    routePath: '/BIN{bin}'
    requirements:
      bin: '[a-zA-Z0-9].*'
    _arguments:
        bin: 'bin'
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: How does the code look which generates the `<form>`?

Comment: `<f:form action="answer" name="pxa-survey" arguments="{survey: survey}">`

Comment: Do you add the #VALUE# to the link in the form? If not, would it help to have the correct URL? AFAIK the form don't add GET parameter by default.